# Move an item from one div to another and back again using jquery

Tags: jquery

Item 1

```
<div id=i2><span id=e2>Item 2</span></div>
```

When I click on Item 1 it should be deleted and moved to i2 and when I click on Item 1 again it must go back to i1

Yes, I tried `append()`, it goes to i2, but on clicking again it does not move back to i1

How do I get to do it.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You can't click on item 1 after deleting it - probably you meant _when I click on item 2 again_

Comment: Click on item 1, it moves to i2, leaving i1 empty or with other items

Comment: Can you describe in HTML terms what you want?  I.e., after you click on Item 1, what would the entire thing look like if expressed in HTML?  And again, what would it look like after you "click on Item 1 again"?

Comment: How do you want it after first click: `<div id="i2"><div id="i1">Item 1</div>Item 2</div>` or `<div id="i2">Item 1 Item 2</div>` or something else?

Comment: @amarghosh
On first click
<div id=i1></div>

<div id=i2>
Item2
Item1
</div>

On Second click, ie., Either on Item 1 or Item 2 in i2, it should move up to i1, in the below case I clicked on Item 2

<div id=i1>Item 2</div>

<div id=i2>Item 1</div>

Comment: I edited the question to add <span> with id to each of the items

Comment: You're effectively swapping the inner contents of the two divs with two clicks, is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#i1").toggle(function(){
        $("#e1").appendTo("#i2");
    },
    function(){
        $("#e1").appendTo($(this));
    }); 
});
</script>
<div id=i1><span id="e1">Item 1</span></div>
<div id=i2><span id="e2">Item 2</span></div>
```

This will repeat the actions for the two clicks. For the first click e1 will be appended to i2, for the second click reverse of this happens, and third click it will repeat first click action and so on.

If you want to attach click event to the span then you can do like this

```
$("#e1").toggle(function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#i2");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).appendTo($("#i1"));
    });
```

If you have repeating elements then you can give them a class name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("span.clickspan").toggle(function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#i2");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).appendTo($("#i1"));
    }); 
});
</script>
<div id=i1>
    <span id="e1" class="clickspan">Item 1</span>
    <span id="e2" class="clickspan">Item 1</span>
    <span id="e3" class="clickspan">Item 1</span>
    <span id="e4" class="clickspan">Item 1</span>
    <span id="e5" class="clickspan">Item 1</span>
</div>
<div id=i2><span id="e6">Item 2</span></div>
```

See a ***[working demo](http://jsbin.com/atiru)***.

Comment: @rahul

Assuming there were a 100 e+i in each #i1 and #i2.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 0):

Because the text "Item 1" becomes part on the div(i2).

Comment: @hallie: right and I can do that, now how do I move it back to i1 with the same id.

Comment: Please have a look at the question I have edited it to add span with id to each item 1 and item 2

Comment: She's only moving the content of the div which is "Item 1". Moving the text again back to div(i1) will need splitting text content of the div(i2).