# HTML/CSS moving images from one box to another on click.?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML/CSS . just playing around with adding an image gallery on a webpage.
I want to be able to create a table with two column
Column A and Column B

Column A will have a bunch of image icons

Column B will have be empty at first (or contain a default image when the page is loaded)

When someone clicks on an image in Column A, I want that image to be displayed in column B.

Is this something I can do with CSS?

Can someone show me how to do this?  maybe a link to a good tutorial or something?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this with css, you can do it throw javascript. Do you need javascript/jquery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a **jsFiddle** just for the fun of it: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3277/

With CSS, you can't do anything with clicks. But you *can* show the hidden picture when you hover the thumbnail, via a bit of a hacky selector:

```
table#cssTable tr td:first-child:hover + td img
```

This rule says:

- `table#cssTable`: For table with id "cssTable"
- `tr td:first-child:hover`: When you hover the first cell in a row
- `+ td img`: Select the image in the adjacent cell.

I also created a small AngularJS app for clicking an image. Here you hide the show the image via the directive `ng-show="showPicture"`, and toggled with `ng-click="togglePicture()"`. This is the controller:

```
$scope.showPicture = false;

$scope.togglePicture = function () {
    $scope.showPicture = !$scope.showPicture;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

css is mainly used for styling so I doubt you can do it with css. but I guess with some code abuse you can make something like that. But if I were you I would do it with javascript.

Comment: is there a good tutorial or something on how to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407096/move-an-item-from-one-div-to-another-and-back-again-using-jquery

This is an answer on this site that uses jquery to do so, it covers everything you need.